# Laravel 5.2 restoring php artisan make:auth changes.

Tags: laravel-5

I have generated  login using php artisan make:auth command in laravel 5.2. I do not need it any more. I want to remove this login/logout/signup and other files generated by this command. HOW ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are located in `\resources\views\Auth\` , also there is a route you should remove it from your `Route.php`

```
Route::auth();
```

Comment: Is there any artisan command to delete the changes made by  php artisan make:auth command ?

Comment: As far I know there ain't any undoing for commands by commands, You just need to delete the files

Comment: Ok I will do so !